# In Proxy how to tell if user is expecting promise?

Tags: javascript, reflection, proxy-classes

I have setup a proxy to "promisify" callbacked functions like this:

```
const browser = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function(target, name, receiver) {
        return function(...args) {
            if (userExpectsPromise) { // how to detect this?
                return new Promise(resolve => chrome[name](...args, resolve))
            } else {
                return chrome[name](...args);
            }
        };
        return target[name];
    }
});
```

What this does is allows user to do `browser.***('arg1', 'arg2')`, this will call `***` on the `chrome` branch.

However some of the `***` on `chrome` branch accept a final argument of a callback. When it does, a user adds a `.then` so they would do - `browser.***('arg1', 'arg2').then(.....)`. I need to detect/intercept if user did a `.then`. Is this possible?

My other option would be to hardcode which `chrome.***` accept a callback, but that is not safe way, as the `chrome.***` API is always evolving.

Comment: I'll remove my comments, just realised you're using `new Proxy` - something I've not used before - reading documentation now (I like the look of this proxy thing!)

Comment: Thank you brother @JaromandaX ! :)

Comment: one thing ... `return target[name];` is unreachable code

Comment: I don't think you need any special handling ... just always `return chrome[name](...args);` - because if `chrome[name]` is function that is expected to return a promise, it will return a promise

Comment: hmmm, perhaps I misunderstand the requirement now that I look closely at your code - are you trying to "promisify" a function that uses a callback in the case of the "user" using `.then` on the proxied call?

Comment: Yes sir! Exactly! I couldn't think of that word! `promisify` is what I'm trying to do! haha

Comment: I don't think there's a reliable way to do this, because the only way I can think of doing it relies on the number of arguments passed in to the "proxy" being one less than expected by the proxied function - and since javascript functions can be called with any number of arguments, regardless of how many are "declared" in the definition, this isn't reliable at all - and you can't tell, on the call of a function, if there's a `.then` afterwards

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX for your help - heah I'm stumped too, I'm researching Reflect right now - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/